# hide ul when user clicks anywhere site

Tags: autocomplete

my code is :

```
function autocomplet() {
    var min_length = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $('#country_id').val();
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajaxname.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {keyword:keyword},
            success:function(data){
                $('#country_list_id').show();
                $('#country_list_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#country_list_id').hide();
    }
}


function set_item(item) {
    // change input value
    $('#country_id').val(item);
    // hide proposition list
    $('#country_list_id').hide();



}
```

and i wana hide ul (country_list_id) when user click on anywhere ?

and im not good in ajax :(

so any one can edit this code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to hide the id when the user click basically anything.

Then here.

```
$(document).on("click", () => {
  $('#country_list_id').hide();
})
```